# Gradle: Could not find method includeBuild() for arguments

Tags: gradle

Really confused here... using `includeBuild(file(rootProject.projectDir).getParent())` in settings.gradle.

Could not find method `includeBuild()` for arguments [/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext] on settings 'example' of type `org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.`

gradle wrapper 2.14.1

Comment: I think `includeBuild` came in gradle 3.1

Comment: agree, the Gradle 3.1 has this composite build thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, user tim_yates.

Gradle 2.14.1 does not feature includeBuild.

Switching to a Gradle version 3.1 wrapper solved my problem.